# Cannot ping Raspberry Pi 3 b+

Tags: networking, wifi, connection, internet, dns

My Raspberry Pi 3 b+ will not allow me to ping it even though I've ping'd and ssh'd into it plenty of times before now.

I can ping my main computer from the pi but not the other direction.

```
ping hostname.local
ping: cannot resolve Hostname.local: Unknown host
```

If I use `ifconfig` on my Pi and get the IP address manually, then I can ping it.

```
ping pi_ip_address.local
PING Hostname.local (pi_ip_address): 56 data bytes
```

Comment: This is not a ping problem, it is a DNS problem.

Comment: I can (generally) ping my Pi on the local network using hostname.local or IP address. If you cannot this is a problem in your computer or router. Ping by hostname is an ARP issue - this can be a complex issue, but is unrelated to the Pi. Refreshing the arp cache can resolve this issue.

Comment: Is your "main computer" a Windows PC?

Comment: Do you use static ip addresses? What is the ip address of the RasPi? Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.

Answer (score 1):

If your "main computer" is Windows, then this is likely the cause of the problem... "the problem" being that Windows seems to have adopted [zero-configuration networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) a bit differently than Linux and Apple.

Since I'm not sure your "main computer" is Windows I won't speculate further. But if it is, the people at [AdaFruit have a couple of unique ideas that may help.](https://learn.adafruit.com/bonjour-zeroconf-networking-for-windows-and-linux/overview) Try one of their solutions first, and if that doesn't resolve it, let us know.